# SQLite Syntax Error when it should not

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios, syntax-error

In a monotouch application, I am using this code to insert a value:

```
string sql = "insert or ignore into [translation] values (\"7d8281e2-3f0d-4f51-a6bd-bf91af90dc4a\",\"113a1275-e7a0-452d-a1e1-9043c1139584\",\"1\",\"Gömlek\")";
var cmd = _repository.Execute(sql);
```

where repository is instance of a class that extends SQLiteConnection. This exact statement works totally fine in RazorSql. But when I execute it with my code, it gives me:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: near ""Gömlek"": syntax error
  at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (IntPtr db, System.String query) [0x0001b] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Database/SQLite.cs:1564
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00000] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Database/SQLite.cs:1000
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00022] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Database/SQLite.cs:903
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Database/SQLite.cs:299
  at MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp.LevelImporter.ImportCsv (Int32 level) [0x000f6] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Service/LevelImporter.cs:117
  at MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp.LevelImporter.DownloadLevel (Int32 level) [0x0002a] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Service/LevelImporter.cs:61
  at MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp.LevelImporter+<StartDownloading>c__AnonStorey12.<>m__2C (System.Object ) [0x00000] in /Users/serhat/Projects/MyApp.Mobile/trunk/MyApp.Mobile.iOSApp/Service/LevelImporter.cs:49
```

and the exception instance contains no other information. What am I missing?

Edit: I think it has something to do with letter "ö". When I replace that with "o", the query works fine. How can I make it work with unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

Parameterizing the query solved the problem.

```
insert or ignore into [tablename] values (?,?,?,?,?)
```